# Why image doesn't showing React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

i new in React-Native. 
In this case i wanna to show my image from server in to my card.

```
class Events extends Component {
state = {
    listsofEvents: []
}
componentWillMount() {
   eventsRef.on('value', (data) => {
        this.setState({ listsofEvents: Object.values(data.val()) })
        console.log('this data', Object.values(data.val()))
    })
}

renderEvent() {
  const { listsofEvents } = this.state;
  console.log('out of renderdasds', listsofEvents)
  return listsofEvents.map(event => <EventDetail key={event.title} event={event} />
  );
}

render() {
    return (
        <Container>
          <Content>
             {this.renderEvent()}
          </Content>
        </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

And Detail Component

```
    const EventDetail = (props) => {
    return ( 
        <Card >
            <CardItem>
                <Left>
                    <Body>
                        <Text>{props.event.title}</Text>
                    </Body>
                </Left>
              </CardItem>
              <CardItem cardBody>
                    <Image
                          style={{width: 400, height: 250}}
                          source={{uri: 'http://oisooyqzw.bkt.clouddn.com/emergency.jpg'}}
                        />
              </CardItem>
              <CardItem content>
                  <Text>{props.event.poster}</Text>
              </CardItem>

       </Card>
    );

};
```

I see only blank card, for image i use one image-cloud Qiniu, if i put any other image it's working, in older version of my app (using ionic) it's working, but with React don't wanna! Where is actually problem?